# GridView no dibuja las imágenes cargadas con Picasso

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un adaptador personalizado el cual utiliza un GridView. La función consistía en mostrar una galería de imágenes que pudieran ser descargadas. El problema que tengo es que ya no se dibujan las imágenes en cada item del GridView.

Estoy usando la librería Picasso. Estuve leyendo mucho sobre los posibles errores, ya que mi aplicación en la sección de Logcat me arroja un error como:

> Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Estuve leyendo en otros lugares que las imágenes debían de pesar menos de 100KB (yo solo estoy cargando una sola imagen que pesa 26KB de 200x200 pixeles). ¿Qué puede esta pasando?

Les comparto parte de mi código:

GridActivity.java

```
public class GridActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> names;
    private GridView gridView;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);

        Toast.makeText(GridActivity.this, "saludos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("https://www.laciudadbabasonica.com/wallpaper/imagen-1-rz.jpg");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_grid, names);

        gridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int layout;
    private List<String> names;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<String> names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.names = names;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.names.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHoleder holder;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            //Inflamos la vista que nos ha llegado a nuestro layout personalizado
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHoleder();
            holder.myWallpaper = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wallpaperItem);
            //holder.myText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mitexto);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder  = (ViewHoleder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //View v = convertView;


        String currentWallpaper = names.get(position);



        //TextView mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mitexto);
        //mText.setText(currentName);
        Log.i("wallpaperintent", "cargando url: " + currentWallpaper);
        //holder.myText.setText(currentWallpaper);
        Picasso
                .with(this.context)
                .load(currentWallpaper)
                .into(holder.myWallpaper);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHoleder {
        private ImageView myWallpaper;
        private TextView myText;
    }
}
```

activity_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GridActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="#f2f2f2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperItem"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Y esto es lo que obtengo al hacer debug:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes el permiso para internet definido dentro de tu AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Sí, compañero. Sí lo tengo.

Comment: puedes mostrar el debug de errores, el que sale en rojo a ver si hay alguno que diga cual es el problema, pues allí no veo nada raro

Comment: Claro que sí. Gracias. Mira, recibo con frecuencia este error: `E/GmsContextObserver: Received context data while not listening` y `E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de batallar por 4 horas decidí darle el mismo alto que las imágenes que intentaba cargar por Picasso, ya que las imágenes tienen una dimensión de 200x200 pixeles. A mi `ImageView` le di un `height` de 200 y el problema se solucionó. Espero que esta respuesta sirva para futuras referencias.

grd_item.xml (editado)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#f2f2f2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wallpaperItem"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```